# How to upload multiple image in admin panel grid form?

Tags: magento-1.7, image, forms, grid-serlization, grid-layout

Here, I would like to upload multiple image in admin panel grid form in magento. I create images upload in admin panel grid form.
Here I attached my image upload coding.

```
[....]

$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'image',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_design')->__('design Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_design')->__('design Image'),
            'required'  => true,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        ));
[....]
```

when i change multiple upload image  by using this argument. `'multiple'=> 'multiple'`
Here my code:

```
 [....]

    $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
                'name'      => 'image',
                'multiple'  => 'multiple',
                'mulitple'  => true,
                'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_design')->__('design Image'),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_design')->__('design Image'),
                'required'  => true,
                'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
            ));
    [....]
```

And also i put name value as array[] just like this `'name'      => 'image[]',`.
Nope, i am not getting any result, still single image will be uploaded. How to create multiple image upload concept in magento. Can any one Help me to solve this problem.Please guide me.

Comment: I'm really interested in this question as well, took a quick look and this block seems to be behind the media uploader for products `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader`. I'll follow your question closely :)

Comment: Adding `multiple` has no effect because of this: `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract::getHtmlAttributes`. In there you will find the element attributes that you are allowed to set. Maybe you should write you custom input renderer that allows `multiple`.

Comment: Hi @SanderMangel...Thank you for encourage me..:)-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing [my comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-admin-panel-grid-form#comment12158_8816), here is how you can achieve what you need.
You need to create your custom renderer for the image field. For this create this class in your module:

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Entity]_Helper_Image extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image{
    //make your renderer allow "multiple" attribute
    public function getHtmlAttributes(){
        return array_merge(parent::getHtmlAttributes(), array('multiple'));
    }
}
```

Now at the top of your `_prepareForm` (where you add your fields) add this line before adding any field:

```
$fieldset->addType('image', '[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Entity]_Helper_Image');
```

Or if you want to be "politically correct" add it this way:

```
$fieldset->addType('image', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('[module]/adminhtml_[entity]_helper_image'));
```

This will tell Magento that in your current fieldset, all the fields with type `image` should be rendered by your own class.

Now you can add your field like similar to how you did it:

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'image[]', //declare this as array. Otherwise only one image will be uploaded
            'multiple'  => 'multiple', //declare input as 'multiple'
            'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_design')->__('design Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_design')->__('design Image'),
            'required'  => true,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        ));
```

That's it.
Don't forget to replace the placeholders (`[Module]` and others) with your values.
**[EDIT]**
This is basically the way to override/add any input type you want. Create your own class that should extend the original input class (or `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract` if you add a new one) and declare it at the top of `_prepareForm`

Comment: Hi @Marius... Thank u for proper guide..I have one doubt..which is refer _[Entity]_ and entity given in class? can you please explain it...

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU. Entity is what you are editing. it can be a product, an article...What is the class name of your form? From that I can tell you what entity should be. In theory it can be anything. You can even remove that from the class name but I added it there to keep a consistency in the code.

Comment: @Marius for multiple i have to create separate file button to upload image ? or how it can handle multiple image

Comment: @Marius : This didn't work for me. Still load one image upload. Please any suggestions on it?

Comment: Excellent ! This question should be protected

Comment: @Marius can you please let me know how to show multiple images in backend admin form also how to delete it?

Comment: @Rajan. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Any similar solutions for magento 2.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to make the same thing but with module  `Aw_blog` but when I add  the

```
$fieldset->addType('image', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('aw_blog/adminhtml_blog_helper_image'));
```

The page form for my post's blog is white.

PS: the field upload one image is a success but for multiple don't.

[mymodule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HcWd.png) 
[image]