# Multiple images are not uploading in the custom module

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, module

Hi I am following the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223886/magento-custom-module-multiple-image-uploader-in-adminhtml-form)
but the multiple images are not uploading in the form.

I click on the browse button in the form, new window opens for selecting the images and when I tried to select more than one images from there, it is not happening.
It only select one image at a time. How can I select multiple option from here.

what should I do to do this correctly.

Here is my `image form`

```
<?php
class Vertax_Blog_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Tab_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{

   $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
   $this->setForm($form);
   $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('image_form',
                                   array('legend'=>'image'));
$fieldset->addType('image', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('blog/adminhtml_article_helper_image'));
//$fieldset->addType('image', 'Vertax_Blog_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Helper_Image');

$fieldset->addField('image', 'file', array(
        'label'     => 'Image',
        'required'  =>  false,
        'name'      => 'image[]',
    'multiple'  => 'multiple',
    'mulitple'  =>  true,
    ));

if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBlogPostData()) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBlogPostData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBlogPostData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry('article_data')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('article_data')->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload multiple image in admin panel grid form?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-admin-panel-grid-form)

Comment: @Marius I am following the solution provided here but its not working.

Comment: Try with `$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(` instead of `$fieldset->addField('image', 'file', array(`

Comment: @Marius thanks for this. I figured that out. Its my bad, I didn't notice that. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this question would have an answer...
Based on the comments, the issue is the field type:

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'file', array(...))
```

should be

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(...))
```

More explanations on how to add a multiple image upload can be found [in this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8823/146)

Comment: i used this for selecting multiple images and it works but still images are not uploading the code breaks on `$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image')` line. I dont know how can I do it properly.

Comment: @Waseem. This seams like a totally different question. Ask a new one and post your controller code in there.

Comment: Thanks I asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064832/varien-file-uploader-is-not-uploading-files-in-custom-module-in-magento) take a look.