# Magento 2 - How to upload multiple images in admin panel grid form?

Tags: magento2, upload, multiple-file-upload

I got the solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-admin-panel-grid-form/8823#8823), but it is for Magento 1.
Please show me how can i achieve it in Magento 2.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 3):

I had got the solution for that.

Please check below code that's working for me.

```
$fieldset->addField('images', 'image', array(
        'name'      => 'images[]',
        'multiple'  => true,
        'label'     => __('design Image'),
        'title'     => __('design Image'),
        'required'  => true
    ))->setAfterElementHtml('
        <script>
            require([
                 "jquery",
            ], function($){
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $( "#images" ).attr( "multiple", "true" );
                });
              });
       </script>
    ');
```

Comment: can you please post the controller part of the code, how to upload the multiple files via $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory');

Comment: Did you get any solution for this I also want to upload the multiple images from frontend